# How to render static url_for paths when using app.app_context()

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a simple script to generate static pages from a basic Flask app. To do so, I'm rendering the views through app.app_context(). However, this requires to set the SERVER_NAME configuration. This results in full instead of static url paths once rendered.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] ='localhost:5000'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about', methods=['GET'])
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        view_functions = app.view_functions
        for key, value in view_functions.items():
            if key is not 'static':
                html = render_template(f'{key}.html')
                with open(f'{key}.html'), mode='w') as file:
                    file.write(html)
```

Now, in the HTML files I'm using url_for to render url paths like this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
```

Once rendered, I expect static url paths:

```
# Expected: 
<a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>

# Reality:
<a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:5000/about">About</a>
```

Is there a way to render static instead of full url paths when using app_context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `_external=False` to the url_for:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about', _external=False) }}">About</a>
```

Converse is true if you're rendering links for emails, for example, you would want to set _external to True.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works. It turns out I need '/about.html' instead of '/about' though. Is it possible to render the html file extension within a url_for() call?

Comment: No, you don't need to since you can use Jinja's syntax of `{% include "/path/to/template.html" %}`